# IDE0051 error with Unity default methods (Start, Update)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Default Unity methods marked as unused. And gives an error message ["IDE0051. Private member '. Start' is unused"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Cxs.png)
I tried to: Edit->Preferences->External Tools->[Regenerate project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHonI.png)

Unity version is 2020.3.25f1
Unity 'Visual Studio Editor' Package version 2.0.12.

VS Community 2022 version 17.0.4 (also tried on VS Community 2019 version 16.11.8)

Windows 11 Home (21H2)

Comment: Rather sounds like a warning ... Ignore it .. have you installed the `Unity Tools for Visual Studio` via the Visual Studio installer?

Comment: @derHugo Yes i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed at Unity 'Visual Studio Editor' Package version 2.0.16.

Answer (score 0):

According to this forum post by Bunny83 you should use protected for your MonoBehaviour Methods.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1746268/faulty-unused-errors-in-vscode-for-update-and-star.html

Comment: So i found that Unity deleting some lines (witch generates by Unity) in 'Assembly-CSharp.csproj' file. 
https://prnt.sc/25llyt2
So i have to somehow to stop this.